# HA in Kubernetes and master node number

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, high-availability

I would work with HA in Kubernetes, and i would identify how many nodes should i prepare to manage X workers

Is there a forumla to apply ?

And what is the best solution to implement as Load Balancer ? HaProxy or Nginx ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes you can manage up to 5000 worker nodes.

You need at least 3 control plane nodes, then you can scale this nodes vertically first, then horizontally ([documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/)).

If you plane to deploy a fixed number of control plane nodes, I don't have a strong opinion about the LB to use. Otherwise you need a dynamic LB.